# Single supply op-amp saturates every time

Tags: simulation, differential, kicad, single-supply-op-amp, ngspice

Given a reference voltage level, I need to pick the difference with respect to that reference, amplify it and then convert it to digital. (Yes, I want to measure small voltage drops between two lines).

I'm trying to achieve this by using a OPA379AIDCKR (https://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=10&gotoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Fopa379) in the following configuration:

[image: schema]

My simulation result:

[image]

As you can see I'm not able to make it work since the computed output should be (2.2)*(V+ - V-) = 0.66 V. Instead the simulation saturates.

I've tried with many resistance values and different configurations, but I always see the same.
What did I do wrong? Is there something I'm missing?

PS: Spice model taken from manufacturer's website.

Comment: Also probe on the **inputs of the opamp**, are the values what you expect?

Comment: Please use the standard symbol for op-amps, not boxes. It makes it hard to read.

Answer (score 4):

Your symbol pinout order does not match the model's pinout order.  Here is the relevant section in your [OPA379.LIB](https://www.ti.com/lit/zip/sboc126) file:

```
* END MODEL FEATURES
*
* PINOUT ORDER +IN -IN +V -V OUT
* PINOUT ORDER  1   3   5  2  4
*
.SUBCKT OPA379 1 3 5 2 4
*
Q21 25 26 24 QNL
R77 27 28 200
R78 29 28 200
R79 30 26 100
```

Notice how the order is listed as: `+IN -IN +V -V OUT` ?
Well, your symbol needs to match this order.  It does not, but KiCad/Eeschema has an option to help you in dealing with this problem within the `"Spice Model Editor"`.  It is called `"Alternate node sequence"` and is found at the bottom of the second tab.  This allows you to shuffle the symbol's pin order so that it matches the SPICE model/subcircuit.  In this specific case, you want to set it to `1 3 5 2 4`, as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Yes! That did the trick! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

There is something wrong with the model and/or symbol, perhaps the connections to inputs are reversed. It should work, at least within a few mV at the output.

Comment: Yep. Your circuit is fine. You have a reality failure.

Comment: Vcm is to 0.1V outside both rails.

Comment: SOLVED: Yes it was a pin misconfigurtion.. see here http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/ngspice-eeschema.html#OpAmp for alternative pin configurations  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your pins are in the wrong circular sequence:

[image: OPA379]